# How to update a specific row in a table without a primary key in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, row, primary-key

I am trying to use an UPDATE query in MySQL database table. I have primary key that auto increments in the table but I don't want to use this key when doing this query. This is because this column doesn't restart its count when records are deleted so there are gaps in the table. For example, if I delete row 25 and then INSERT a new row, the ID of that row/will be 26. So back to my question, I want to know how I can edit the values of one specific record/row. I have tried the following:

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `first_Name` = "Robert" WHERE (SELECT * FROM `employees` LIMIT 1,1)
```

This was my try of updating the firs_Name in the second row only. But it doesn't work. There is some syntax error. Is there any other way to do this? Or can I solve the problem of the auto-incrementing column (I would prefer an answer that ignores this).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you update a row, don't you know its id ??

Comment: what will happen with ur Code when the first 3 guys are called Robert and u want to Change the 2nd ? When u know what record u have to Change, u have its Primary id. use it that way.

Comment: @jiboulex I do know what the ID is but I don't want to use that in the query because the auto-incrementation in MySQL is not very good (in my opinion)

Comment: in order to do any updates u have to use uniq values. Name is not a uniq. if u want to edit an existing user then use his ID. or give us more info what ur script should do in the end.

Comment: @KikiTheOne I do have a unique column: the ID column. So would I have to do: UPDATE `table_name` SET `first_Name` = "Robert" WHERE ID='number'  ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the id ? It is here for a reason ! There also is a reason why the auto increment creates gap when you delete rows : you don't want a resource to replace another ! Your opinion is wrong about mysql auto-incrementation !

Comment: so please edit ur question and tell us what u want where . Do u want to Edit USERS ? so u have a list of users and u click on EDIT and then u do update? or where did ur Code is going to work ?

Comment: @jiboulex So is there a way I CAN replace the record with another? If not, then how can I edit the record?

Comment: Replacing a record with another is an update. Use the id to do so !

Comment: @jiboulex So is there no way to use the LIMIT feature in the UPDATE query?

Comment: This seems more likely to do with a problem with your design flow than MySQL auto increment. The type of update you appear to be trying to do would require a unique identifier for example the primary key.

Comment: A few comments about why not using the primary, because sometimes that is not available. Consider, we are updating products, all products are uniquely named. We want to update product quantity on the product name. Salesperson doesn't know the ID. Doesn't care. We have a text input with product names, they choose name. So, it can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your User Table Looks like this:

```
id    |   first_name
1     |   Robert
2     |   Sam
```

Now you want to edit SAM so he is called Samuel.

## #1

Print the Users

```
Select * From Users
```

Then build a Loop to give user back in a table. Then you can do your Actions with it.

## #2

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['userid']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {
        mysql_query("UPDATE Users SET first_name = '".$_POST['first_name']."' where id=".$_GET['userid']." LIMIT 1");
    }
    else
    {
        $get_user_sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = ".$_GET['userid']." LIMIT 1";
        $query_user = mysql_query($get_user_sql);
        $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_user);
        print '<form action="'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'" method="post">';
        print '<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="'.$user['first_name'].'" />';
        print '<input type="submit" />';
    }
}
else
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        print '<a href="?userid='.$row['id'].'">edit user <b>'.$row['first_name'].'</b></a><br />';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: btw u should use mysqli and not mysql and u should clean the Code with `'.$_XYZ.'` to `'$_XYZ'` depending on ur php Version and on good practice